# AWS Glue - DynamicFrame with varying schema in json files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

**Sample:**
I have a partitioned table with DDL below in Glue catalog:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test`(
  `id` int, 
  `data` struct<a:string,b:string>)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `partition_0` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
```

The underlying data in S3 is json files with varying schema meaning that some elements may not exist in some files but exist in other.

In the this sample partition_0='01' contains json file with all elements:

```
{"id": 1,"data": {"a": "value-a", "b": "value-b"}}
```

The file in partition_0='02' does not contain element data.b:

```
{"id": 1,"data": {"a": "value-a"}}
```

**Issue:**
When I create DynamicFrame in Glue (I use Python), its schema depends on the data that I query. If I include the data from partition_0='01' then all elements are present in the schema.

```
id_partition_predicate="partition_0 = '01'"
print("partition with 'b'")
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_source_database, table_name = "test", push_down_predicate = id_partition_predicate).printSchema()

partition with 'b'
root
|-- id: int
|-- data: struct
|    |-- a: string
|    |-- b: string
|-- partition_0: string
```

```
print("both partitions")
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_source_database, table_name = "test").printSchema()

both partitions
root
|-- id: int
|-- data: struct
|    |-- a: string
|    |-- b: string
|-- partition_0: string
```

If I query only data from partition_0='02' then element data.b does not exist in the DynamicFrame schema even though it exists in the table definition.

```
print("partition without 'b'")
id_partition_predicate="partition_0 = '02'"
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_source_database, table_name = "test", push_down_predicate = id_partition_predicate).printSchema()


partition without 'b'
root
|-- id: int
|-- data: struct
|    |-- a: string
|-- partition_0: string
```

**Question:** How create DynamicFrame or DataFrame that always contains all elements from the Glue table's schema?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this solution:

```
id_partition_predicate="partition_0 = '02'"
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_source_database, table_name = "test", push_down_predicate = id_partition_predicate)
dyf.printSchema()

df=dyf.toDF()
try:  
    df = df.withColumn("b", col("data").getItem("b"))
except:
    df = df.withColumn("b", lit(None).cast(StringType()))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
root
|-- id: int
|-- data: struct
|    |-- a: string
|-- partition_0: string

+---+---------+-----------+----+
| id|     data|partition_0|   b|
+---+---------+-----------+----+
|  1|[value-a]|         02|null|
+---+---------+-----------+----+
```